# Unable to login Lubuntu Desktop openLDAP

Tags: server, lubuntu, openldap

Our admin is trying to install an openLDAP system for some network machines.

I'm listing all the steps here so that someone may point out the breaking mistake.

### Objective

1. Setup a centralized authentication system with Ubuntu server and
   lubuntu clients.
2. The users should have their personal directories kept on the server and accessible on every client they login.

### Errors

1. After the steps below the openLDAP user `test1` is able to login through terminal, but the desktop login keeps looping and returning.
2. Any new user 'test2' ( *without creating folder on client machine* ) created on server throws an error on client:

   ```
   Could not chdir to home directory /home/users/test2: No such file or director
   ```

### Setup

Using a Ubuntu Server 13.04 and Lubuntu 13.10 client

```
Server IP : 192.168.0.55
Client IP : 192.168.0.100
```

1. The Lubuntu clients were installed through PXE booting over the network and installation files cached through `apt-cacher-ng`.
2. A preseed file provided some of the openLDAP details to the client

   ```
   ldap-auth-config ldap-auth-config/ldapns/ldap-server string ldap://192.168.0.55
   ldap-auth-config ldap-auth-config/ldapns/base-dn string  dc=organization,dc=lin
   ldap-auth-config ldap-auth-config/ldapns/ldap_version select 3
   ldap-auth-config ldap-auth-config/dbrootlogin boolean yes
   ldap-auth-config ldap-auth-config/dblogin boolean false
   ldap-auth-config ldap-auth-config/rootbinddn string cn=admin,dc=organization,dc=lin
   ```
3. Both server and clients are normal virtualbox VM's and no fancy hardware is involved. Already checked `ls -lah`. The output is :

   ```
   total 8.0K
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 21 09:20 .
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jul 21 09:20 ..
   ```

### Server Steps

1. Installed openLDAP on the server `sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils` and specified administrator password
2. Edited configuration file to reflect new domain `sudo nano /etc/ldap/ldap.conf`:

   ```
   BASE dc=organization,dc=lin
   URI ldap://192.168.0.55
   ```
3. Ran the configuration assistant `sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd`

   ```
   ? Omit Server Configuration - No
   ? DNS Domain Name - organization.lin
   ? Organization Name - Organization Name
   ? Admin Password - <adminPassword> and re-enter
   ? Back-end Database - HDB
   ? Remove Database - Yes
   ? Move Old Database - Yes
   ? Allow LDAPv2 - No
   ```
4. Tested LDAP Server `sudo ldapsearch -x` and verified the settings
5. Installed phpLDAPAdmin `sudo apt-get install phpldapadmin`
6. Created symbolic link `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpldapadmin/ /var/www/phpldapadmin`
7. Edited phpLDAP configuration `sudo nano /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php` and set the following

   ```
   $servers->setValue('server','name','Organization LDAP Server');
   $servers->setValue('server','host','192.168.0.55');
   $servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=organization,dc=lin'));
   $servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=organization,dc=lin');
   ```
8. Restarted the Apache service 'sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart'
9. Opened ports 'sudo ufw allow 80' and 'sudo ufw allow 389'
10. Tried logging into phpLDAP Admin `http://192.168.0.55/phpldapadmin/`

    ```
    Login DN : cn=admin,dc=organization,dc=lin
    Password : <adminPassword>
    ```
11. Now tested phpLDAPAdmin

    ```
    Created a POSIX group - Employees
    Created a POSIX Account below it - test1 / password1
    ```
12. The home directory for the user is `/home/users/test1`

### Client Steps

1. Installed `sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap libpam-ldap ldap-utils ldap-auth-client nscd` on client
2. Edited `sudo nano /etc/ldap.conf` and entered following information :

   ```
   base dc=organization,dc=lin
   uri ldap://192.168.0.55/
   ldap_version 3
   rootbinddn cn=admin,dc=organization,dc=lin
   pam_password md5
   ```
3. Edited `sudo nano /etc/ldap.secret` and entered following information : `<adminPassword>`
4. Secured File `sudo chmod 600 /etc/ldap.secret`
5. Ran `sudo auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap'
6. Edited `sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-password`
7. Set line 26 as `password [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die] pam_ldap.so use_authtok try_first_pass`
8. Created directory `sudo mkdir /home/users`
9. Installed NFS-Common `sudo apt-get install nfs-common`
10. Edited `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and entered the following:

    ```
    192.168.0.55:/home/users/   /home/users/   nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192, timeo=14,intr
    ```

### References

http://www.unixmen.com/openldap-installation-configuration-ubuntu-12-1013-0413-10-debian-67-2/

http://www.unixmen.com/configure-linux-clients-authenticate-using-openldap/

http://www.unixmen.com/openldap-installation-configuration-ubuntu-12-1013-0413-10-debian-67/

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingphpLDAPadmin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me the error is not in LDAP, but in automatically creating home directories of new users. According to [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM):

> Include this in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` if you want to automatically create home directories when users first login:
>
> ```
> session     required      pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
> ```

Note that looping back to login screen happens whenever the home directory can't be written to - this may be because the directory doesn't exist, or doesn't have write permissions, or has a full disk quota, etc.

Comment: You're a lifesaver.